# Find path of python program in execution

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

In my terminal, I can see a python program in execution:

```
python3 app.py
```

where can I find `app.py`?

I've tried to look in the `/proc/$pid/exe` but links to the python interpreter.

I have many `app.py` programs in my system, I want to find out exactly which is in execution with that pid.

Comment: where is your `app.py` file ? go there and run `python3 app.py`

Comment: @zimdero this is my actual question. How can I find this app.py file?

Comment: `find / -type f -name "app.py"`

Comment: Thanks @0x00, I've also tried `updatedb` and `locate app.py` but I've several of them.

Comment: Isn't it in the current directory of that shell process?

Comment: @0x00 i think better to find from `~/`

Comment: you can try recursively search this line on entire filesystem `grep -r "python3 app.py" /`

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo thanks for the answer, but I don't want to "find a file on Linux", I want to find the exact running file from a program. I know how to find files, I wouldn't ask if the answer were so obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i ran a short test on my machine and came up with this... maybe it helps:

1. find the *process id* `PID` of the job in question:

   `$ ps -u $USER -o pid,cmd | grep app.py`

   the `PID` will be in the first column. assign this number to the variable `PID`.
2. find the current working directory of that job:

   `$ ls -l /proc/$PID/cwd`

   (for more info: `cat $ cat /proc/$PID/environ`)

your `app.py` file will be in this directory.

Comment: I think (but didn't check) that `environ` will contain `PWD` as it was when the process was launched, whereas `cwd` would reflect the current working directory, which can change if the script executes `chdir`.

Comment: Hello there! Environ hadn't the PWD variable in it, and had apparently no helpful informations. I've found out that the program was in a docker contianer, by check the CWD file, that stated that the cwd was /app that obviously, wasn't in my root. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

check the file

```
/proc/[PID]/environ
```

There is PWD variable contains full path of the directory containing the executable file.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently there is no PWD directory in there.

Comment: it's variable in /proc/[PID]/environ file

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac Os X please try using:

```
sudo find / -type f -fstype local -iname "app.py"
```

If you are **not** on Mac Os X you can use:

```
sudo find / -mount -type f -iname "app.py"
```

The find command will start from your root folder and search recursively for all the files called "app.py" (case insensitive).

Comment: I do not recommend doing this. Although this solution might look simpler, it *will* scan your entire filesystem. And if you have mounted some remote shares, running this command will take extra long time to complete, stressing your hard drive, network, and your patience.

Comment: Your update is wrong. `local` is not a valid file system type.

Comment: Correct, it is only valid on Mac. Added also GNU find details.   @AndrejsCainikovs